# 404 error when using routing with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to set up routing with angular and angularfire but am having trouble.

```
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute', 'firebase', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'SampleCtrl'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

  });

app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $firebase){
  console.log('LoginCtrl')
})
```

when I try to hit localhost:8000/login I get the following error message

```
Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.
```

How can I set up simple routes with ngRoute and AngularFire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the default router you need to use a hash in the url.

```
localhost:8000/#/login
```

If you want to remove the hash, that's another story.

You'll need to use the `$locationProvider` and set `html5Mode()` to true. From there you'll have to stop using `$window.location.href` to change routes and use `$location.path()`.

Then you'll have to get a server or use a service like [Firebase Hosting](https://www.firebase.com/hosting.html) that supports [URL rewrites](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/url-redirects-rewrites.html).

Comment: This material is covered in the Angular.js tutorial. It's a great primer before digging into AngularFire (i.e. Firebase + Angular)

Answer (score 0):

play-around $location here (see the "test output" part, this helps me understand $route), hope this helps.

http://ngtutorial.com/learn/route.html#/_tblcontents_5